# Using JFileChooser to read a file name

Tags: java, swing, relative-path, jfilechooser, absolute-path

I am using the File input stream to input a file

---

```
String filename="D:\\abc.txt";
File file = new File(filename);
```

---

It works fine up till now. Now I want to input the file name using `JFileChooser` and then do the same. But `JFileChooser` returns a string like this `D:\abc.txt`. My code is as follows

---

```
public static String fileChose()
{
    JFileChooser fc= new JFileChooser();
    int ret = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (ret== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
    {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String filename= file.getAbsolutePath();
        return filename;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

---

The problem is with needing to filenames separated by `\\` instead of `\`. Can't I directly input the filename from JFileChooser in such a manner so as to directly use it as an argument in

---

```
File file = new File(Classname.fileChose());
```

Comment: Your declared string "D:\\abc.txt" is the same string as the "D:\abc.txt" string returned by the method, because `\` is an escape character so `\\` in code is actually `\`.  With that said, I'm having trouble discerning what your question really is.

Comment: I understand that it is an escape character. But the argument in File requires using \\ format rather than \. So I want to know whether the filepath in that format can directly be acheved or not ?

Comment: I agree with Vulcan, but more importantly, why dont you change the method to return the `File` itself instead of the filename ? like `File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
 return file;` You are anyways making it a file

Comment: @prajeeshkumar: Ok.. I think you provided a better solution. Thank you..

Comment: @CSSS The argument in file *does not* require a "\\ format" at all.  In Windows, \ is the file separator, so you only need one, not two.  Using \\ is necessary on the string declaration side, because "\\" is not literally two backslashes, it is compiled to a single backslash.

Comment: You should always use "/" as file separator. It will work on Windows and Unixes. With "\\" the program will only work in Windows (you are running Java to _write once run everywhere_, right?). But the solution of using a `File` instead of a `String` is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

`String s = fileChooser.getSelectedFile()`

```
public String removeExtension(String s) {

    String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    String filename;

    int lastSeparatorIndex = s.lastIndexOf(separator);
    if (lastSeparatorIndex == -1) {
        filename = s;
    } else {
        filename = s.substring(lastSeparatorIndex + 1);
    }

    int extensionIndex = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (extensionIndex == -1)
        return filename;

    return filename.substring(0, extensionIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try out

```
if (code == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
               File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
               fileName = selectedFile.getName();
               FileInputStream fis = 
                  new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
               InputStreamReader in = 
                  new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8")); 
               char[] buffer = new char[1024];
               int n = in.read(buffer);
               String text = new String(buffer, 0, n);
               myPane.setText(text);
               in.close();
            }
```

demo:

```
public class JEditorPaneFileChooser implements ActionListener {
   JFrame myFrame = null;
   JEditorPane myPane = null;
   JMenuItem cmdOpen = null;
   JMenuItem cmdSave = null;
   String dirName = "\\herong\\swing\\";
   String fileName = "JEditorPane.txt";

   public static void main(String[] a) {
      (new JEditorPaneFileChooser()).test();
   }
   private void test() {
      myFrame = new JFrame("JEditorPane JFileChooser Test");
      myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      myFrame.setSize(300,200);

      myPane = new JEditorPane();
      myPane.setContentType("text/plain");
      myPane.setText(
         "Hello computer! - \u7535\u8111\u4F60\u597D\uFF01\n"
         + "Welcome to Herong's Website!\n"
         + "\u6B22\u8FCE\u4F60\u8BBF\u95EE\u548C\u8363\u7F51\u7AD9"
         + "\uFF01\nwww.herongyang.com");
      myFrame.setContentPane(myPane);

      JMenuBar myBar = new JMenuBar();
      JMenu myMenu = getFileMenu();
      myBar.add(myMenu); 
      myFrame.setJMenuBar(myBar);

      myFrame.setVisible(true);
   }
   private JMenu getFileMenu() {
      JMenu myMenu = new JMenu("File");
      cmdOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
      cmdOpen.addActionListener(this);
      myMenu.add(cmdOpen);

      cmdSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
      cmdSave.addActionListener(this);
      myMenu.add(cmdSave);
      return myMenu;
   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(dirName));
      chooser.setSelectedFile(new File(fileName));
      chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

      FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
        ".txt and .java files", "txt", "java");
      chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

      Object cmd = e.getSource();
      try {
         if (cmd == cmdOpen) {
            int code = chooser.showOpenDialog(myPane);
            if (code == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
               File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
               fileName = selectedFile.getName();
               FileInputStream fis = 
                  new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
               InputStreamReader in = 
                  new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8")); 
               char[] buffer = new char[1024];
               int n = in.read(buffer);
               String text = new String(buffer, 0, n);
               myPane.setText(text);
               in.close();
            }
         } else if (cmd == cmdSave) {
            int code = chooser.showOpenDialog(myPane);
            if (code == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
               File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
               fileName = selectedFile.getName();
               FileOutputStream fos = 
                  new FileOutputStream(selectedFile);
               OutputStreamWriter out = 
                  new OutputStreamWriter(fos, Charset.forName("UTF-8")); 
               out.write(myPane.getText());
               out.close();
            }
         }
      } catch (Exception f) {
         f.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

ref : http://www.herongyang.com/Swing/JEditorPane-File-Chooser-Dialog-Box.html